# Dynamic variable failure

Tags: next.js13, next-intl

I have a problem, when my locale is zhtw, in the json file, the value with the variable is invalid, and I get an error code: 'INVALID_MESSAGE', originalMessage: Incorrect locale information provided ', but if I change my locale to zh-tw, that's not going to happen, because I need the name zhtw for my route, so I don't know how to solve that problem

I hope zhtw has the same effect as zh-tw, variables can be used

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.